# Bind Microsoft Azure Function App 2.0 preview to 0.0.0.0

Tags: c#, azure

I have a Microsoft Azure Function App 2.0 preview written in C# which binds to http://localhost:7071.

[image]

How do I get it to bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost so I can access it from another machine on my local network?

Looking at these [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) I can see how to specify the port in the `local.settings.json` file

`"Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071, 
    "CORS": "*" 
}`

But not which Network Interface to use.

Coming from a Rails background I would do this with: `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

How do I do this in the .net / Azure Function world?

Comment: You should be able to access it from the other machine by IP address - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482164/how-can-i-access-localhost-from-another-computer-in-the-same-network

Comment: Thanks I’ve tried this.  Even tried using the IP address to access it from the local machine but it’s not worked.  I have Windows Firewall switched off too.

Comment: There's always [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: If anyone came after http://0.0.0.0:7071 did not work just use http://localhost:7071

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### UPDATE —

You don't need this sorcery anymore as the functions host now listens on `0.0.0.0:7071` by default:

```bash
$ func -v
2.0.1-beta.33

$ func | grep Runtime
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.11933.0

$ func host start | grep -i listen
Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
```

---

### NOW DEPRECATED —

If you're on Windows,

```
C:\>netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8081 ^
        listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=7071 connectaddress=127.0.0.1


C:\>netsh interface portproxy show all

Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:
Address         Port        Address         Port
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
0.0.0.0         8081        127.0.0.1       7071


C:\>netstat -an  | findstr 8081
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

C:\>netstat -an  | findstr 7071
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7071         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

To test it out:

```
C:\>curl.exe http://192.168.111.4:8081/api/HttpTrigger -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 28 Mar 2018 18:25:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

"Oh hai."
```

To get rid of portproxy:

```
C:\>netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=8081 listenaddress=0.0.0.0
```

On Linux, iptables your way through it, on a Mac... i don't know, nginx your way out? Okay, there seems to be a [**`pfctl`**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/248064) tool, probably inherited from BSDs?

Although Kestrel is the server, setting the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:7071"` has no effect. The function host is probably bootstrapped with `localhost` in code, which may be a hint that you're not supposed to expose it naked and you should reverse proxy into it.