# How can I call my Function App API from another system?

Tags: c#, api, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have created an Function App using Visual Studio 2017 and I created some APIs. That API was worked on my system very fine. But from another system its gets the "bad request / site can't be reached".

[image]

My question is, how can I call my API from the another system? Anyone please give me solution.

Comment: `192.168.1.17` is your PC's IP address (local)? And you are running it locally?

Comment: Yes, it's my system IP but, it is also not working in my system . I'm using "localhost" instead on IP address. That's my problem I can't access my API with IP.

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49541736/4148708. `func host` isn't really meant to be used _as-is_ in production, should be wrapped by a heavy-duty reverse proxy like nginx.

Comment: _What's wrong with Kestrel that it needs nginx on top?_ you may ask. Fair question. Probably nothing wrong with naked Kestrel, i opened an issue to get an answer from the folks that build the runtime - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3184

Comment: Have you bind 127.0.0.1 ip in your service so that your azure function can't be accessed by other ip except localhost.

Answer (score 3):

If you created a v2 function, please check your function CLI output when debugging locally. At the third line, there should be `Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071`

If you see `Now listening on: http://localhost:7071`, it means your function CLI is old so that it still binds to localhost, which stop you accessing function with your local IP.

Apparently solution is to use the latest CLI. On VS menus, Tools->Extensions and Updates, find `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`, update it to latest version(15.0.40617.0). Then things should work with new CLI.

Note that local functions can only be visited by systems in the same LAN, otherwise you should make the function available in public, have a look at [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). And if you use v1 function, its latest CLI still binds to localhost, have to resort to tools like ngrok if needed.

Answer (score 2):

At VS debugging site, IIS Express and localhost + port are used by default.

In order to use IP address and multi domain debugging, we can find `applicationhost.config` under `C:\Users\...\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` and find the following code:

[image]

Add a similar line in the `<bindings>` tag:

```
 <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:7071:192.168.1.17" />
```

Then open the CMD command window as an administrator:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.17:7071/ user=everyone
```

Finally, you can access this site with IP address

More information for your reference: [IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request/39599030)

Comment: Yes, I get a message "Successfully registered" but still I can't access the API using IP address... I thing can I restart my system?

Comment: @IsmayilS Yes, try to restart your system