# Django Rest framework API is not working on another PC of same network

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created an API named http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/allEvents and it works perfectly in my browser and on the Postman app.

However, when I am trying to access the API from another PC of the same network it return an error:

> this site cannot be reached

Comment: how did you try from the *"other PC"*? which was the URL?

Comment: and when you run your application, try to set up ip 0.0.0.0 for example `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: http://127.0.0.1 is localhost , it say that it's using the ip of the currently using computer(in your case 127.0.0.1 is the computer that you using), what you searching for is [local network's IP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19482207/11225821)

Comment: Yes i'm using localhost hitiing this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/allEvents` and its working fine where the server is running but not working to the other pc on same network

Comment: hitting this url on both browser and postman on other pc ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your settings.py file add your local ip to allowed_hosts.for example:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.50']
```

and also run your local server using below command (set port number whatever you want):

```
python manage.py runserver 0:8080
```

and on browser at the other computer,call below url:

```
http://192.168.1.50:8080
```

IP address is your IPv4 Address `192.168.0.101` not the django default `127.0.0.1`

Comment: your solution is work but you have not mention which ip address is used . i have updated your answer

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your setting files and make changes to ALLOWED HOSTS.

for example:

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] #this will allow all the ip's in your local network to access your url
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xx.xx.xx.xx'] # this will allow only "xx.xx.xx.xx" in your local network to access your url.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Ubuntu host
please allow the port:8000

```
sudo ufw allow 8000
```